# Aligning Checkbox to the right

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

I am trying to align the checkbox so that its at the right of recurring but its not working. I have tried the inspect the elements and tried different ways but still i cant get it to go to the right.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row center">
    <p>Recurring:</p>
    <form action="#">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check1">
        <label for="check1"></label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `p` element and the `form` element the property `display:inline-block;`.

Both the p and form elements have the `display:block;` property by default.

```css
p{
  display:inline-block;  
}
form{
  display:inline-block;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row center">
    <p>Recurring:</p>
    <form action="#">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check1">
        <label for="check1"></label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add your "Recurring" text to the label [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/hk0pdrL5/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row center">
    <form action="#">
        <label for="check1">Recurring</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check1">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to mark the question as solved if it's ok for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `inline-block` divs to align the elements inline:

https://jsfiddle.net/Bendrick92/0o6mwdtz/

```css
.left, .right {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row center">
    <div class="left">
      <p>Recurring:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <form action="#">
          <input type="checkbox" id="check1">
          <label for="check1"></label>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```